# Как добавить несколько экземпляров класса T в свойство List of T при создании экземпляра другого класса ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, crud

### Имеется класс `Skill` и класс `Course`

```
public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string? Name { get; set; }

        public string? Description { get; set; }

        public List<Skill>? CourseSkills { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must be authorized!")]
        public string CreatorUserName { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Skill
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string? Description { get; set; }

        public List<Course>? Courses { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class CourseViewModel
    {
        public List<SelectListItem>? SkillSelectList { get; set; }

        public int SelectedSkillId { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string? Description { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must be authorized!")]
        public string CreatorUserName { get; set; }
    }
```

При создании экземпляра класса `Course` через стандартный **ASP.NET CRUD** интерфейс необходимо как-то добавлять несколько уже существующих экземпляров класса `Skill` из списка внутри `select`-a

---

*Как я себе это представляю:*
(input) **[_ введите Имя для Course _]** 
(select) **[_ выберите Skill _]** (button) **[_ добавить Skill в Course _]** 
(button) **[_ создать Course _]**

---

При нажатии на (button) **[_ добавить Skill в Course _]** ниже текущего `select`-a появляется еще один `select` и `button`, где можно было бы так же выбрать еще `Skill` 
И при нажатии (button) **[_ создать Course _]** в метод `Create` контроллера `CourseController` передавался бы `List_of_Skills` или `Array_of_Skills` (+ прочие свойства, типа `Name` и тд)

Либо просто в одном `select`-e выбирать несколько и передавать их в контроллер в виде `List` или `Array`

---

Пока что разобрался только с добавлением одного `Skill` в `Course` :

```
@model Prog.Models.ViewModels.CourseViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Create course</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="mb-3 form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="mb-3 form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="CreatorUserName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="CreatorUserName" class="mb-3 form-control" value="@User.Identity?.Name" readonly="true"/>
            </div>  
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                    <select class="form-select" asp-items="Model.SkillSelectList" asp-for="SelectedSkillId">
                        <option value="0">-- Please Select a Skill --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-outline-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Идеи, варианты?

Comment: добавил немного кода :)
может нужен какой-то еще?

Comment: добавил. еще что-то?

Comment: `authorizated` => `authorized`, а так стало намного легче читать вопрос. Я не спец по ASP.NET Core или EF Core, думаю вскоре кто-то заглянет и ответит, я всего-лишь помог лучше оформить вопрос. Кстати, имена сущностей из кода лучше выделить с помощью ` а не ** - `item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял вы хотите передать в модель `CourseViewModel` несколько `Skill`.
Тогда в классе `CourseViewModel` заменим свойство

```
public int SkillId { get; set; }
```

на свойство

```
public List<int> SkillIds { get; set; }
```

так как нам нужен список, а не один элемент.

---

Далее, чтобы с представления получать список значений, к тегу `select` добавьте атрибут `multiple`.
В общем должно получиться так:

```
<select multiple class="form-select" asp-items="Model.SkillSelectList" asp-for="SkillIds">
</select>
```

на самом представлении это будет выглядеть так:  [image: Стандартный мультиселект в представлении]

Да, стандартный мультиселект выглядит не очень, к этому вернёмся позже.
Теперь зажимаем <kbd>CTRL</kbd> и выбираем нужные элементы (в стандартном только так).
Далее нажав `Create` в контролере мы увидим выбранные элементы, для примера выбрал 1 и 3: [image: Полученные id-шки с представления]

---

Теперь изменим стандартный мультиселект. Если погуглить есть много вариантов/стилей для мультиселекта, мне понравился отсюда https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select. И в итоге будет выглядеть так, и через <kbd>CTRL</kbd> уже выбирать не надо

[image: 3]

По ссылке описана установка, но если коротко:

- через `nuget` установить `bootstrap-select`
- в файле `_Layout`:

  - в `head` добавить `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">`
  - после `jquery.js` и `bootstrap.js` добавить `<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.14.0-beta3/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>`
- к селекту добавить класс `selectpicker` *благодоря этому преобразование в селект что на последнем скрине происходит автоматически*

Comment: Класс,  именно так.

Comment: все в целом работает, спасибо большое, но вот с `selectpicker` `select` вообще пропадает (сделал все как надо) ну то уже ладно, с `CTRL` буду выбирать :)

Answer (score 0):

*Модель Course*

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }

    public string? Description { get; set; }
    
    public int SkillId { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("SkillId")]
    public virtual Skill? Skill { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must be authorized!")]
    public string CreatorUserName { get; set; }
}
```

*Фрагмент кода метода Create для Контроллера Course (для архитектуры MVC)*

```
        public IActionResult Create()
    {    
         // извлечение скиллов из базы данных и конвертация в объект специального типа
         IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SkillsDropdown = _db.Skills.Select(i=> new SelectListItem { Text=i.Name, Value=i.Id.ToString()});

        // создание ViewBag для передачи в представление
         ViewBag.SkillsDropDown= SkillsDropDown;
         Course course = new();
         return View(course)
    }
```

*View*

```
@model Course
<form method="post"
    .....
// блок с выбором скилов из выпадающего меню
<div>
 <select asp-for="SkillId" asp-items="@ViewBag.SkillsDropDown"
</div>

//передача данных в метод пост из полей ввода
 <div>
   <input type="submit" value="Create"
</div>
```

Также в контроллере нужно будет создать метод Create типа POST, для записи в базу данных нового Course.
ViewBag это костыль, и правильнее создавать ViewModel для работы с данными о Course.
Подробный пример решения, для вашего случая в курсе по [ссылке](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm_HvURobtaz8GrLaI-iQhhc).

Comment: Спасибо, но у вас, как и в моем примере, мы берем всего один `Skill` для `Course`, но мне прям **надо** `List<Skill>` или что-то в этом роде.   `ViewModel` как раз и использовал в третьем "куске" кода `CourseViewModel`

Comment: Тогда нужна более сложная модель, где для одного Course, нужно добавить список Skills, тогда делаете еще таблицу SkillsCourses, где хранятся записи о всех связях между Course и Skills, то есть в каком то поле указывается как внешний ключ ссылка на Course, в следующем поле той же записи указывается  ссылка на конкретный Skill. Запрос к этой таблице выдаст список всех Skill, для конкретного Course.

Comment: Я уже делал подобное, когда реализовал логику учета Заказов в Интернет магазине, и там для всех заказов была единая Таблица, в которой хранились записи об отдельных позициях в заказах, но при запросе из этой таблицы, для одного заказа формировались все записи по товраным позициям.

Comment: так у меня и есть эта "более сложная модель" в классе `Skill` имеется `List<Course>`, а в классе `Course` есть `List<Skill>` и как раз в бд благодаря этому создалась таблица `CourseSkill` где соотносится скиллы к курсам. Вопрос же не о бд, я понять не могу как во `View` взять несколько `Skill` для одного `Course` и присвоить их ему